# In SpringBoot why do we need to have separate annotation @ExceptionHandler Annotation when I can write the code in Catch?

Tags: spring-boot, exception

why do we need @ExceptionHandler for the exception class separately when we can write our error message and details in Catch block itself? Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try..catch` block to handle the exception at backend level or I should say for developer's help so that they can see the exception and fix.

However, you would not send this technical exception message to UI or CLIENT because that message may contain some private or sensitive information.

So we create a **GLOBAL Exception handle** where we can specify what message or code we want to send to UI or Client. Also, we can specify HTTP status with the response.

[Read](https://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler-handlerexceptionresolver) this for more detailed understanding.

Answer (score 0):

@Lakshmi G.....
In Servlet environments, you can combine the @ExceptionHandler annotation with @ResponseStatus, to define the response status for the HTTP response.